# Mathcad's Ruby syntax

Tags: mathcad

I am looking for any documentation for what Mathcad calls "Ruby syntax".

When one copies (select then ctrl + c) the following expression from Mathcad Prime UI

[image]

it copies the expression in a format called "ruby syntax" which looks like this:

```
(:= (@LABEL VARIABLE Force) (= (/ Torque (@ID Drive_Shaft (@SUB radius))) (@RSCALE (@MATRIX 6 1 (* 9.714 (^ 10 3)) (* 4.857 (^ 10 3)) (* 3.238 (^ 10 3)) (* 2.429 (^ 10 3)) (* 1.943 (^ 10 3)) (* 1.619 (^ 10 3))) (@LABEL UNIT N))))
```

I could not find any documentation for this syntax and it does not seem to be written in the [Ruby Language](https://ruby-doc.org/) syntax.

Comparing these two, I cannot find any similarity in the syntax!

There is no information about it in their website and the only place it is mentioned is in [this example](https://support.ptc.com/help/mathcad/r8.0/en/index.html#page/PTC_Mathcad_Help/API/example-6_Cpp_code_generator.html#)

Does anyone know where I can find any documentation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently its a mistake in their example documentation.

The copied code is in S-Expression and not in Ruby!